# Q: System.InvalidOperationException: Call Init first (OCR TESSERACT) error in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

The `if (tessResult)` is always false, and it must be true to perform the tesseract OCR, anyone can help me?

```
if (!_tesseractApi.Initialized)
    await _tesseractApi.Init("eng"); 

  var photo = await TakePic();
  if (photo != null)
  {
      // When setting an ImageSource using a stream, 
      // the stream gets closed, so to avoid that I backed up
      // the image into a byte array with the following code:
      var imageBytes = new byte[photo.Source.Length];
      photo.Source.Position = 0;
      photo.Source.Read(imageBytes, 0, (int)photo.Source.Length);
      photo.Source.Position = 0;

      var tessResult = await _tesseractApi.SetImage(imageBytes);

      if (tessResult) 
      {
        _takenImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => photo.Source);
        _recognizedTextLabel.Text = _tesseractApi.Text;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: it sounds like you are not successfully initializing Tesseract

Comment: yah but I already initialized it, but I don't know why is it failed. Do you know how to fix it? @Jason

Comment: nope, I'd suggest asking the Tesseract developers, or looking at their sample app (if they have one)

Comment: ohhh okay thank you @jason

Comment: have you checked the log for any error messages from the Init step?  There are many posts on SO about errors during the init related to missing permissions

Comment: This is the error that is popping up, System.InvalidOperationException: Call Init first. @Jason

Comment: Check the log/output, not the exceptions.  Or try reading some of the other tesseract questions on SO to see what some common problems are.

Comment: Actually I searched common problem, and I saw my problem but that problem was closed and didn't answer the problem @Jason

Comment: Do you have `tessdata` on your phone?

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov I don't have that tessdata in my phone sir but I already put it in the project of android and ISO.

Comment: @JonasJacinto please read the doc https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin#utilisation

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov Yes sir I already did that in my project but still not working because of that not initialized problem

Comment: @JonasJacinto so you do have `tessdata` on your phone. Then can you share the logs?

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov this is the Log sir

Answer (score 1):

Put the Tesseract train file(in your case English tesseract train file) inside the your assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

try to import tessdata to your project:
[image: try to import tessdata to your project]

Comment: Although your answer could be 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...